# How to xd file to psd file converter

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a solution to convert XD files to PSD. Files i'm intending to export will be flat SWF files with layout as per attached example (PSD). The most important bit is that it can be exported at high quality. I've researched this and not found

Comment: I think StackOverflow is not the right place for this question. I think [Super User](https://www.superuser.com) is better

Answer (score 1):

You can checkout the online tool Photopea at photopea.com
Open your XD file in it, then at the left top Files menu you will find save as psd. Save the file and open it using Photoshop. This is working for most of the designers. Try your luck!:)